# How to iterate over a Form in Html, store the data in a variable in Json, send it back to Django Backend as POST data

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, javascript-objects

I need to iterate over an Html Form and get the data as JSON obj and send it to the Django backend to get data as objects.all().  Is this possible?

In this form I am iterating over a student detail list that I have rendered to the template using Django.

my form

```html
<form method="POST " id="studentform">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Admission No</th>
        <th scope="col">First Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Present Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for student in student_names %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">
          <div class="form-group ">

            <select class="form-control st" style="appearance: none;" id="admission_number" name="admission_number">
              <option>{{student.admission_number}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>
          <div class="form-group">

            <select class="form-control st" style="appearance: none;" id="first_name" name="first_name">
              <option>{{student.first_name}}</option>
            </select>

          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="form-group">

            <select class="form-control st" style="appearance: none;" id="last_name" name="last_name">
              <option>{{student.last_name}}</option>
            </select>

          </div>
        </td>

        <td>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control st " style="text-align: center;" id="attendance" name="attendance">
              <option>Yes</option>
              <option>No</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="birthdaytime">Grade :</label>
      <select class="form-control" style="appearance: none; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 500;" id="grade" name="grade">
        <option>{{user.studying_grade}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="birthdaytime">Subject :</label>
      <select class="form-control" style="appearance: none; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 500;" id="subject" name="subject">
        <option>{{user.assigned_subject}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">

    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

any help or suggestions, tutorials much appreciate on how to do this..  Thanks

Comment: `let formInputs = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(myForm).entries()) `

Comment: Hi. Mister Jojo.  Thanks for replying.  Please be a little more specific about the code.  I am new to javascript.  I need to iterate over my form data , assign it to a dict or list and send it to backend in django.  You support is much appreciated on this.  Thanks

Comment: `FormData(myForm).entries()` iterates over the form of the element & `Object.fromEntries` does it in JSON format, everything is documented on mdn. There are also a lot of answers here about that. Your question unnecessarily increases the list of millions of questions/answers on this site, so you are supposed to show before what you may have experienced and not ask for a free answer with a course in JavaScript programming. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  & https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593